# Field must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function

Tags: sql, group-by

I'm trying to write a query containing subqueries, which contain aggregate functions. I get an error message telling me that I should include some of my fields in the GROUP BY clause of my main query, in which I don't use any aggregates.
I'm pretty new at SQL so this might be a silly mistake but I have been on it for days and I can't figure it out with the existing content.

```
WITH B AS 
(
  SELECT
    A.Week
   ,A.ASIN
   ,A.GL
   ,sum(Case when Week = 'W1' then Total_GV_Price/Total_GVs else 0 end) as Wk1_AVG
   ,sum(Case when Week = 'W2' then Total_GV_Price/Total_GVs else 0 end) as Wk2_AVG
 FROM A
 WHERE Total_GVs > 0
 GROUP BY A.Week, A.ASIN, A.GL
)
, C AS 
(
  SELECT
    B.Week
   ,B.ASIN
   ,B.GL
   ,B.Wk1_AVG
   ,B.Wk2_AVG
   ,Case when NVL(Wk1_AVG,0) =0 then NULL else (Wk2_AVG - Wk1_AVG) / Wk1_AVG end as Price_var
  FROM B
  GROUP BY B.Week, B.ASIN, B.GL, B.Wk1_AVG, B.Wk2_AVG
)
SELECT C.*
FROM C
HAVING Price_var >= 0.3
```

So the error message is telling me: column "c.week" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function. And I don't understand what i'm not grouping or what I should be grouping.

I appreciate any comments and thank you for your help !

Comment: Remove the `GROUP BY` clause from the C subquery. You are not aggregating anything there. And change `HAVING` to `WHERE` in your main query, because again you are not aggregating anything there.

Comment: So calculations within a CASE are not considered as aggregations? It worked :)

Comment: @Jonathan: aggregation is the use of an aggregation function e.g. `sum()`, `avg()`, `min()` or `max()`

Comment: The error message seems to indicate you are using PostgreSQL. However the `nvl()` function seems to indicate you are using Oracle. Which one is it?

Comment: @Jonathan: It works, because your `GROUP BY` clause doesn't do anything. You say you want to aggregate rows so as to have no duplicates per Week/ASIN/GL/Wk1_AVG/Wk2_AVG, but there are none, which you ensured in your B query. `CASE WHEN` doesn't aggregate, because it deals with values of a single row. Aggregation means to take values from multiple rows and end up with one value (say the maximum, minimum, or average of the values).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answers !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure, because I can't reproduce the situation. But I think the problem lies in the `SELECT ... FROM C` at the end. You are using `HAVING`, which is used for aggregated columns (i.e. `SUM(...)`). Because the last `SELECT` has no aggregation a simple `WHERE` would suffice.

```sql
...
SELECT
C.*
FROM
C
WHERE Price_var >= 0.3
```

Hope this helps...

Comment: and for C table, no need to use group by.

Comment: @Jonathan: Then click the tick to accept the answer.